# How to fetch the static data to the form using reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have a reactive form, on click of new button, i am able to get the same section again.
But here the options in the select field doesnt show up and also, i get an error as soon as page loads.

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'itemRows -> ContactName'
>
> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'itemRows -> Phone'
>
> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'itemRows -> Relationship'

Can anyone help me to solve this issue and help me to get dropdown list in Relationship.

On everytime page load i get that error and also data inside drop down also not visible.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to put both `formArrayName` and `formControlName` on the same HTML node. Try to follow the pattern as described in the [`FormArrayName` documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName). In your case, I'd start by putting `formArrayName="itemRows"` on a new `div` that is one level higher.